# How to get users without subgroups in ActiveDirectory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script that give me all users from specific groups as list (User, user, user - where "," is my list separator) and then I add them into *.xlsx file (after split them). What I want, is checking that actual group member is user or subgroup.

Actually, I check every single group member is it on my list, but this solution isn't good enough.

Is there some way to check it while I receive members list from each group?

**EDIT**

Script to get all members from specific groups:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$groups = Get-ADGroupMember "CN=${GroupName},OU=Members,OU=FolderMain,OU=Start,DC=local"

foreach($element in $groups)
{
 $element.name -creplace " - [0-9]{6}",""
";"
}
```

This code give me a list of group members like:

> USERNAME, USERSURNAME ; USERNAME, USERSURNAME ; ... ; USERNAME,
>   USERSURNAME

But some groups contain other groups. What I want is check that the member is groups or user; when group - it shouldn't be showed on my list.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are asking. Should you include you code so we can look at it? Do you mean find users that are _not_ in a certain group?

Comment: I edited my post and add script.

Comment: @Matt - no, I mean that if some group is member of group that I actually create list - it shouldn't be added to that list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Bacon Bits has a good answer for this case then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe it through `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ADGroupMember [...] | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }
```

Note that you may want to consider the `-Recursive` switch on `Get-ADGroupMember`, which will get users in the groups within the targetted group.

Note also that `Get-ADGroupMember` gives computer objects the `objectClass` of `'Computer'`.  This is different from strict LDAP, where they have an `objectClass` of `'user'`.  You don't need to worry about specifying `objectCategory` here (and can't, as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$groups = Get-ADGroupMember "CN=${GroupName},OU=Members,OU=FolderMain,OU=Start,DC=local"

foreach($element in $groups)
{
if (!$element.Members)
{
Write-Host "Group $element.Name have no members;"
}
 $element.name -creplace " - [0-9]{6}",""
";"
}
```